# [first, ...rest]: A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)

Tags: arrays, typescript, constructor, apply

Setting

```ts
class X {
    constructor(first: string, ...rest: string[]) { }
}

new X(...["foo", "bar"])
```

yields the error

```
A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)
```

This is working:

```ts
new X("foo", ...["bar"])
```

but that's not very handy.

If I use

```ts
class X {
    constructor(...all: string[]) { }
}
```

instead it's working fine, so it must have something to do with me splitting into `first` and `rest`. But is there a way to make this work with split arguments?

Comment: I find that adding `as const` might help (`new X(...["foo", "bar"] as const)`), but not sure if it is a workaround or if it can be applied to the real problem.

Comment: @YangHanlin Thanks, problem is I'm working with non-static (mapped) arrays where I cannot use `const`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `["foo", "bar"]` is `string[]`. If you can't control the type of this with `as const`, because you got it elsewhere, you can validate and narrow the type, for example:

```js
const input:string[] = ["foo", "bar"];

if (!input.length<1) {
  throw new Error('Input must at least have 1 element');
}
const tuple: [string, ...string[]] = [input[0], ...input.slice(1)];
}
```

If the assignment feels silly, I feel this is way more elegant:

```js
const input:string[] = ["foo", "bar"];

function assertAtLeast1Element(input: string[]): asserts input is [string, ...string[]] {
  if (input.length < 1) throw new Error('Input must at least have 1 element');
}

assertAtLeast1Element(input);

class X {
    constructor(first: string, ...rest: string[]) { }
}

new X(...input);
```